# I have files and a copy of the server, not database, can I recreate the website?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have files and a copy of the server, not database, can I recreate the website?

Eccomerce website
Wordpress
all server files

[image: Image of server files]

inside www

[image]

Comment: In a word, no. All content is (or at least should be) stored in the database, as are all of the Wordpress settings.

Comment: Some Backup-Plugins put database dumps somewhere below wp-content, make sure you look there.